# Why do you need OAuth for a read-only reddit instance with PRAW?

Tags: oauth, reddit, praw

According to [the PRAW manual](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html), you need to specify client ID, client secret, and user agent in order to make a read-only reddit instance.  Why is this?  You don't need any authentication to look at reddit with a browser; why should it be different if you automate it?

Is this a restriction imposed by PRAW, by the Reddit API, or neither?

Answer (score 0):

Reddit's API access rules state, "Clients must authenticate with OAuth2".

https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules

Of course there are ways around that limitation, but Reddit is not granting you permission to do so. As a result PRAW 4.0+ enforces the use of OAuth.